# AWS Amplify Datastore, using an observequery, does old data that doesn’t match the query remain on the iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify, datastore

I am using AWS Amplify Datastore in a swift, iOS app, and I have a question that I haven’t really been able to find a definitive answer for in the docs.

I use an “observeQuery” query to hydrate and sync the data to the device initially, and to listen for changes in real-time.

The database contains items that are event based, and occur one (think a list of deliveries, or flights from an airport). I am querying for any events that occur +/- 24 hours from “now”.  This is working great.  My question is, does data pulled down and synced from say 3 days ago still live in the on device data store?  Or does amplify Datastore handle that and only keep a local copy of the data that matches the query that is sent when “observeQuery” is initialized on app startup.

Everything is working fine, I’m just wondering in the behaviour of how data not matching the query is handled in the local datastore.